# Setting :host for different staging servers with one "staging" environment in Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, environment-variables, capistrano

I have 3 separate staging servers set up in capistrano (and may have more at some point). For example:

```
staging.example.com
staging2.example.com
staging3.example.com
```

The capfile for each specifies the same environment though:

```
set :rails_env, 'staging'
```

... and in `config/environments/staging.rb I've had to define default url options:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'staging.example.com' }
```

Unfortunately this eventually results in using the wrong server at some point. For example, while testing on staging2 you could get an email with "staging" set in the url... click it without thinking and then you're on the wrong server.

I didn't want to add a separate environment file for each staging server since there may be quite a few at some point and this is really the only change that is different per server, since it's the hostname.

Is there any way to get around this without using a separate environment file per staging host? Is it possible to use capistrano's `:web` setting as the host url?

```
role :web, "staging2.example.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an APP_CONFIG variable loaded from a yml file on each server as described in this related question: [Re-source .bashrc when restarting unicorn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043358/re-source-bashrc-when-restarting-unicorn)

Also, the original idea for the APP_CONFIG came from [Railscast #226.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use cap to edit the staging.rb file during the deployment. Either using `sed` to edit the hostname in, or maybe simply append the action_mailer line to the end.

Another option: make sure your hostnames are set properly, and let the server fill it in at boot time:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: `hostname` }
```

I don't think cap is set up to handle this unique case.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you so late. In essence, I think this is the right way to go, but I'll probably end up using environment variables of some sort. So, something like `ENV['email_host']`. That way I can define them explicitly on a per-server basis and I don't have to write any conditional code in the rails app itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you generating the email as the result of a controller action? You can use the `HTTP_HOST` header from the request and write the links in the email accordingly.

Comment: Not a bad idea. My question simplifies my use case a bit though so I don't think that'll help much in my case. I can't rely on any request parameters.