# Re-source .bashrc when restarting unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano, unicorn

I have some ENV variables that are sourced for the `deploy` user. (Similar to what [Heroku recommends](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), but without using Heroku.)

My rails app depends on these for certain functions, for example, in application.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: ENV['MY_HOST'] }
```

This is necessary because we have several staging hosts. Each host has `MY_HOST` defined to its correct hostname in `.bashrc` like so:

```
export MY_HOST="staging3.example.com"
```

This allows us to only use one rails `staging` environment, but still have each host's correct hostname used for testing, sending email, etc since this can be set on a per-machine basis.

Unfortunately it looks like when I restart Unicorn using `USR2` it doesn't pick up changes to those variables. Doing a hard-stop and start will correctly load any changes.

I'm using `preload_app = true` which may I'm guessing has something to do with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I went away from this approach altogether in favor of loading my app config from an app_config.yml file. Ryan Bates covers this approach in [Railscast #226](http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2).

The only thing I did differently is that I load a shared app_config.yml for each server I use.  Since I'm using capistrano, I just symlink the file on deploy.

For example, on staging2 my `shared/configs/app_config.yml` looks like this:

```
staging:
  host: "staging2.example.com"
```

... whereas on staging3 it looks like this:

```
staging:
  host: "staging3.example.com"
```

Now my `application.rb` has this line instead:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: APP_CONFIG[:host] }
```

I removed the actual `config/app_config.yml` from git so that it's not included on deploy. (I moved it to `config/app_config.yml.template`.) Then on deploy I use a capistrano task to symlink `shared/configs/app_config.yml` to `config/app_config.yml`:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Symlinks the app_config.yml"
  task :symlink_app_config, :roles => [:web, :app, :db] do
    run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/app_config.yml #{release_path}/config/app_config.yml"
  end
end
```

This strategy has these benefits over using ENV vars:

- Deployed to all nodes via capistrano
- We can do conditional hosts by simply changing the file on the appropriate server
- Unicorn will get changes with USR2 since everything's done inside of rails
- Everything's kept in one place, and the environment isn't affected by some other variables outside of the codebase