# Rails doesn't see environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, unicorn

I am trying to move a Rails application into production but I am having a problem with Rails not seeing my environment variable.

I have the password for my database setup in my .bashrc file like

```
export APP_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD=secretkey
```

In irb

```
ENV["APP_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD"]
```

returns `secretkey`.

Using

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```

and just

```
rails c
```

returns `secretkey` but when starting the application I get

```
Access is denied (using password: NO)
```

I am using a slightly modified version of the init script on "[How To Deploy a Rails App with Unicorn and Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04)" to start unicorn.

It is being hosted on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Comment: Where are you deploying it? Heroku? GoogleCloud? AWS?

Comment: To my own server using Ubuntu 14.04, i'll add that.

Comment: LPT: you can look into environment variables of your process by looking into `/proc/PID/environ`. It's quite helpful for debugging this sort of things.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`export APP_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD=secretkey` is most likely scoping your environment variable to a bash process. Since Unicorn doesn't run as a child of bash process, it doesn't have access to this environment variable.

I'd recommend storing your ENV vars in a single place, such as `application.yml` and loading them into your ruby environment at the start of your application. There are some great tools that do this. I'd recommend looking into Figaro: https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro.

Here's another post relevant to your question: [Re-source .bashrc when restarting unicorn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043358/re-source-bashrc-when-restarting-unicorn)

Comment: Is there any way to put those variables in Unicorns scope? Or is that a bad Idea?

Comment: Yes, you can set them directly in the script that starts unicorn, or in the `unicorn.conf` file. However, one disadvantage of this approach, however, is that your ENV variables won't be accessible for `rake` and the rails console.

Comment: I think Anthony explanation is probably right. But i think storing ENV vars in an yml file is not good. If you do that sensitive information could be committed to SCM, which could be an opening to vulnerabilities.

Please take a look at [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) i think it is what youre looking for.

Comment: Yeah don't commit application.yml! same goes for dotenv.

Answer (score 23):

Try doing `spring stop` followed by `rails c`

[Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) is a rails application preloader that loads the ENV configuration. It might not have loaded the `.bashrc` changes in your case.

Answer (score 10):

Or you forgot to install `gem 'dotenv-rails'`  ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. A simple solution for you would be to run:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production && rails c
```

The reason is that when you do not use the export, the rails can not see the environment variable but you see its value when you execute `echo` on the console.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

> http://railsguides.net/how-to-define-environment-variables-in-rails/

Put your environment variables in `local_env.yml`, and then put this in `application.rb`

```
  config.before_configuration do
    env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
    YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
      ENV[key.to_s] = value.to_s
    end if File.exists?(env_file)
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

For the ones using zsh:

```
echo 'export APP_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD=value' >> ~/.zshenv
source ~/.zshenv
```

Check if it has really been set using:

```
echo $APP_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD # value
```

For running rails applications you might also want to do `spring stop`.